# String to Date in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a column with fields string(VARCHAR) EX: 201207 i am trying to convert to date , But the catch is some of the fields have format of 201207 and some as 20120725 which also includes date TO_Date(201207,YYYYMM) is failing for fields which has dates and vice versa .

```
Columns representation
201207
201208
20120925 
.....
```

Comment: What is the day component for those date strings which only have a year and month?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The last 2 digits of field are dates. Actually i am trying to connect this DB to tableau which is not accepting TO_DATE(YYYYMM) for 20120825 and also not accepting TO_DATE(YYYYMMDD) for 201208 fields , SO it throws an error for vice versa .

Comment: Please answer the question in my comment above so that others may help you with your question.

Comment: We dont have date component in those with only year and month ,

Comment: @Dheeruchow Do you understand, that a valid date contains 3 **necessary** components: **year, month and day**, and it's not possible to construct it, if you don't have one or more of them? If yes, then you need to provide some rule on how to get missing date component.

Answer (score 1):

#### To Date conversion

The simple ISO-date can be parse like this:
`SELECT DATE ('1990-02-09') FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;`

The numeric date can be parsed by using [`TO_DATE`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sf-date) scalar function and adding a *format-literal* as second argument:
`SELECT TO_DATE('199002', 'YYYYMM') FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;`

> `TO_DATE`: Returns a timestamp from a character string that has been interpreted using a character template. `TO_DATE` is a synonym for `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`.

#### Case dependent

To account for your 2 input-cases just add a CASE expression that tests for [`LENGTH`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=functions-length):

```sql
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH(col) = 6 THEN TO_DATE(col, 'YYYYMM')
    WHEN LENGTH(col) = 8 THEN TO_DATE(col, 'YYYYMMDD')
    ELSE DATE(col) 
  END as dt
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

#### See also

- [Convert dd-mon-yy string to date in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752739/convert-dd-mon-yy-string-to-date-in-db2)
- [Convert Decimal to Date in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152499/convert-decimal-to-date-in-db2)
- https://developer.ibm.com/articles/fun-with-dates-and-times/
- https://www.ibmmainframer.com/db2-tutorial/db2-sql-date-time-functions/